# Get value from nested JavaScript object in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, casperjs, associative

I'm trying to dig into a nested javascript array to grab the first instance of an object. Here's the code:

```
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_male_tennis_players', function() {
  this.echo(this.getTitle());

  // Get info on all elements matching this CSS selector
  var tennis_info_text = this.evaluate(function() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('table.sortable.wikitable tbody tr');
    return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) { // Alternatively: return Array.prototype.map.call(...
      return node.textContent;
    });
  });

  // Split the array into an array of object literals
  var tennis_data = tennis_info_text.map(function(str) {
    var elements = str.split("\n");
    var data = {
      name       : elements[1],
      birth      : elements[2],
      death      : elements[3],
      country    : elements[4]
    };
    return data;
  });

  // Dump the tennis_names array to screen
  utils.dump(tennis_data.slice(1,5));
});

casper.run();
```

The result of stdout is this:

```
{
    "name": "Acasuso, JoséJosé Acasuso",
    "birth": "1982",
    "death": "–",
    "country": " Argentina"
},
{
    "name": "Adams, DavidDavid Adams",
    "birth": "1970",
    "death": "–",
    "country": " South Africa"
},...
```

For the `name` element, I'm getting everything from the `tr` row, which matches 2 elements when you look at the target url source. What I want is just the second part of the name element with class "fn"; for instance: "David Adams", "José Acasuso". I'm thinking something like `name:elements[1].smtg` should work, but I've had no luck.

Additionally, how would I print the available object keys from the `elements` object?

Comment: There is no `element` object in your code.

Comment: I meant *elements* object..

Comment: `elements` is an array of strings so there are no keys that you can access besides the array indexes and array functions. I extended my answer a little with a description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first cell contains two elements which contain the name and first name of the player with different ordering. When taking the `textContent` of the whole cell, both name representations are put into the same string, but in the browser only one of them is visible. If you want only to access the visible one, you need to explicitly crawl it.

You could write a custom function that removes the duplicate name from the string, but it is easier to just take the correct element's `textContent`.

This can be easily done in the page context:

```
var tennis_data = this.evaluate(function() {
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('table.sortable.wikitable tbody tr');
    return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
        var cells = [].map.call(node.querySelectorAll("td"), function(cell, i){
            if (i === 0) {
                return cell.querySelector(".fn").textContent;
            } else {
                return cell.textContent;
            }
        });
        return {
            name: cells[0],
            birth: cells[1],
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

> Additionally, how would I print the available object keys from the `elements` object?

`elements` is an array of strings so there are no keys that you can access besides the array indexes and array functions.

Comment: I see what you're doing here, but I'm getting a *syntax error: parse error* when I run it.. Here's what I have at the moment [http://chopapp.com/#ctbxsdqt](http://chopapp.com/#ctbxsdqt)

Comment: You're probably missing a `}` or `});` somewhere (maybe both). Use proper indentation and you'll find the problem fast.

Comment: You also try to return `data` two times. The second `return` is unreachable code.

Comment: That was excellent help guys. The issue was in fact unmatched brackets.. here's the final, working version [http://chopapp.com/#lsnv1zdt](http://chopapp.com/#lsnv1zdt) Thanks